# Gnome Shell resource extraction

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm trying to extract gnome-shell resource using `gresource extract` using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a n;
n=$(gresource list gnome-shell-theme.gresource | cat | tr '\n' ' ')
for r in ${n[@]}
do
gresource extract gnome-shell-theme.gresource ${r}>${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/.}
done
```

but am getting an error:

```
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/eye-not-looking-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/eye-open-negative-filled-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/keyboard-caps-lock-filled-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/keyboard-enter-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/keyboard-hide-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/keyboard-layout-filled-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/keyboard-shift-filled-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/message-indicator-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/pointer-double-click-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/pointer-drag-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/pointer-primary-click-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
./extractshell.sh: line 6: ./theme/icons/pointer-secondary-click-symbolic.svg: No such file or directory
```

Although the `gresource list gnome-shell-theme.gresource` outputs:

```
/org/gnome/shell/theme/calendar-today.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-focused.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off-focused.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/dash-placeholder.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/gnome-shell-high-contrast.css
/org/gnome/shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/eye-not-looking-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/eye-open-negative-filled-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-caps-lock-filled-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-enter-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-hide-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-layout-filled-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-shift-filled-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/message-indicator-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-double-click-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-drag-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-primary-click-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-secondary-click-symbolic.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/no-events.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/no-notifications.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/pad-osd.css
/org/gnome/shell/theme/process-working.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-off-dark.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-off-hc.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-off.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-on-dark.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-on-hc.svg
/org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-on.svg
```

I'm not sure why this is happening when the list output shows that these files exist.
Is my bash script messed up or what could be the reason? Thank you.
P.S - I'm a newbie trying to customize my gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted the remaining ones as well. I hard-coded the resources list in an array and then directly outputted it with file name.

```
declare -a new;
new=(/org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/eye-not-looking-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/eye-open-negative-filled-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-caps-lock-filled-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-enter-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-hide-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-layout-filled-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/message-indicator-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-double-click-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/keyboard-shift-filled-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-drag-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-primary-click-symbolic.svg /org/gnome/shell/theme/icons/pointer-secondary-click-symbolic.svg);

for r in ${new[@]}
do
    gresource extract gnome-shell-theme.gresource ${r}>`echo ${r:29}`
done
```

Thanks, as now I know about mapfile too. @Quasímodo